# Sortable custom column in post table

Tags: wordpress

I added a custom column to wordpress admin post table but I'm not able to get it sortable, button is working but actually nothing happens.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'new_column');
function new_column( $columns ) {
    $column_meta = array( 'meta' => 'Views' );
    $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 5, true ) + $column_meta + array_slice( $columns, 2, NULL, true );
    return $columns;
}


add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_columns' );
function custom_columns( $column ) {
    global $post;
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'meta':
            $metaData = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'penci_post_views_count', true );
            echo $metaData;
        break;
    }
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'register_sortable_columns' );
// Register the column as sortable
function register_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['meta'] = 'Views';
    return $columns;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. However, since the post view count is numeric (I'm assuming), you'll need to add a filter to the request to define that it is to be evaluated as such.  Add this filter, and you should be good with what you have already.

I also recommend renaming your field from `meta` to `views` so as not to confuse the issue if someone else looks at this code, or using a core word like meta.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'new_column' );
function new_column( $columns ) {
    $column_meta = array( 'views' => 'Views' );
    $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 5, true ) + $column_meta + array_slice( $columns, 2, NULL, true );
    return $columns;
}


add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'custom_columns' );
function custom_columns( $column ) {
    global $post;
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'views':
            $metaData = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'penci_post_views_count', true );
            echo $metaData;
            break;
    }
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'register_sortable_columns' );
// Register the column as sortable
function register_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['views'] = 'views';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'request', 'views_columns_orderby' );
// Filter the request to evaluate the meta as a number.
function views_columns_orderby( $vars ) {
    if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'views' === $vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge( $vars,
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'penci_post_views_count',
                'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
            )
        );
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks :-)